# Thymeleaf: Error parsing expression

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template with this code for pagination

```
<ul class="results_perpage"  >
                                    <li th:if="${previous != null}"><a th:href="javascript:movePage(`${previous}`);" class="results_menu" th:text="PREVIOUS"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"           class="results_menu" th:text="${numPage}"></a></li>
                                    <li><a th:href="javascript:movePage(`${next}`);"  class="results_menu" th:text="NEXT"></a></li>
                                </ul>
```

But I have this error

```
Could not parse as expression: "javascript:movePage('${previous}');"
```

I also tried with the grave ascent(`) with the same result

Comment: can you post full html code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use thymeleaf syntax to add context variables

```
th:href="'movePage(\'' + ${previous} + '\');'"
```

Actually I think you should use onClick in place of href.

```
th:onclick="'movePage(\'' + ${previous} + '\');'"
```